# What causes "error in x[[length(x)]] in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app to analyse some pdf documents that works fine. Now I created a new branch with the same functionalities but on a different set of PDF's. But when I run the app now I get the following warning and error message:

```
Warning in structure(unlist(x, recursive = FALSE), class = "tokens",   names = attrs$names,  :

Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.

Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.

Error in x[[length(x)]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

And therefore the app won't run.
I can not find where the error originates from and how to get the app to run. I've tried commenting out each piece of code, but whatever piece of code I try that for, I still get the same error. Can anybody tell me what this error is or how I can find where it comes from?

Comment: I suppose you have a pdf document there without any tokens.

Comment: If the pdf is parsed into strings, I would guess you have a scanned pdf, that is, one that just has embedded images